# XSD Schema using maxOccurs and minOccurs in complextype

Tags: xsd, schema

I am writing a XSD schema file in Visual Studio 2010.  I want to define a complex type to not be required and have unlimited entires in the xml.  I used the minOccurs and maxOccurs attributes but I am getting an error in the editor that these attributes (minOccurs / maxOccurs) are not allowed.  I can add them to simple types but not complex types.  How do you define that a complex type can have 0 to many occurances?

Here is the xsd I was using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="patient" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should still be valid XSD syntax.  Is the VS editor just highlighting it and telling you that it's not allowed?  It may just be reporting incorrectly.

Edit: Oh, you need a sequence of the complex types!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="patients">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="patient" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:elemennt>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I do not understand your edit.  What do you mean by "you need a sequence of the complex types"?  I am new to xsd.  I defined a sequence for the complex type above.

Comment: I actually rushed through my sample code.  The above should be correct now.  You need a root node (`patients`), which is a `complexType` that contains a sequence of `patient` elements.  It's that sequence that can then have 0 or more occurrences.